# Why cannot I install R package "cowplot"?

Tags: r, install.packages, cowplot

When I try doing `install.packages("cowplot")` I get the following output:

```
Installing package into ‘/insertdirectoryname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/cowplot_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1353271 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘cowplot’ ...
** package ‘cowplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘cowplot’
* removing ‘/insertdirectoryname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/cowplot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cowplot’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBoRcoy/downloaded_packages’
```

I have also tried install.packages("cowplot", dependencies = TRUE), which gives me a similar issue as well. I will include my session info below as well. It should be noted that I am prohibited from upgrading R or RStudio due to work related reasons (we use RStudio server), so I have to work with R version 3.5.1.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/R/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps try an older version? E.g. `require(remotes);
install_version("cowplot", version = "0.9.4", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: "I am prohibited from upgrading R or RStudio due to work related reasons" This sounds like a very poor workflow situation.

Comment: Yes unfortunately but it is what it is.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Hi all! Just wanted to provide an update on my situation. I did find a solution to my issue. What I did is download the package from the CRAN website then upload it to the cluster directory that I designated as my library using .lib.Paths(). For some reason I couldn't load it in using library("cowplot"), so instead to load it I went to the Files/Plots/Pkgs/Help screen in the bottom right of RStudio, clicked on the Pkgs tab, and ticked the "cowplot" box. I was then able to use the cowplot package.